# handlebars outside scope array access

Tags: scope, handlebars.js, pyramid

I'm using handlebars within Pyramid.
I'm declaring the array:

```
var profils = [
   "Profil 0",
   "Profil 1",
   "Profil 2',
   ];
```

In the handlebars script:

```
<script id="referents-list-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    {{#each users as |user|}}
        <tr>
            ....
            <td>
                <select name="Profil-{{user.id}}" id="Profil-{{user.id}}" data-id="{{user.id}}">
                    {{#each ../../profils as |profil|}}
                        <option value="{{profil.id}}">{{profil.name}}</option>
                    {{/each}}
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    {{/each}}
```

But `../../profils` doesn't points to the `profils` array.
I went through several posts about this issue and thought `../` would give access to a parent element but it doesn't in my case.

Comment: Kindly add the whole `data` object in the question.

Answer (score 0):

The `../` would not point to the parent array but to the `root` of the object.
Thus I believe you could use `../profils` for the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your contributions.
I finaly implemented it sligthly differently.
I load the handlebars script through a function.
This function takes the profils array in parameters. 
Doing so, i have no more problem to access profils array inside handlebars script.